# About scaling of data in political science

Tags: categorical-data, data-transformation

Sometimes we will see a survey about social and political opinions and social opinions, the author is trying to combine the polling results, fit them into a curve and make some conclusions. Let's say people are being queried on their political tendency (X) which is scaled into 5 degrees (1/2/3/4/5), and social opinions (Y) how much they link the medical insurance system, which is categorized into 3 scales (1/2/3). They would like to find out how X and Y related to people's satisfaction in their social status (Z). I saw a similar survey online all the time, however, I wonder statistically if it is correct to digitalize the opinion into value for regression. For example, if people's response to satisfaction of the current medical insurance system is scaled as DISAPPOINTED(1), NEUTRAL(2) and SATISFIED(3), we may end up with a numeric data Y ranged 1 to 3. But if someone else conducts the same survey but ends up using the following scale  DISAPPOINTED(-1), NEUTRAL(0) and SATISFIED(1), the data will be very different and the regress will change a lot as well. So what is the correct way to scale the data to make it statistically correct?

Comment: That should not change too much: in your example, it may not change the slope of the regression or the correlation, though it may change the intercept (by $2$ if I have correctly understood your example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to use appropriate methods, and only apply statistics built for numerical values to data that does, in fact, contain numerical values. As you allude to, a rating scale system is typically a relative ranking, and the difference between a 1 and a 2 may not be the same as a difference between a 2 and a 3. Because of this, these ratings are *ordinal* data, rather than *numeric* data - there is an inherent order to the choices, but you can't say anything about the interval between the choices. In some cases it may be OK to approximate these ordinal data as numeric, but you're often better off just using ordinal statistics.

Another type of non-numeric data is *categorical* data, which is similar in many ways, except that it does not have an inherent ordering. Suppose you want to find an association between some numeric value and political leaning, which could be Democrat, Republican, or Independent. There is no inherently logical way to assign these numeric values of 1, 2, and 3, so you should not attempt to do so and find some correlation. You should use categorical association measures here, rather than ordinal or continuous ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I should say categorical data instead. To make it simple, if we are surveying customer's tendency to sweetness (dislike, neutral and like), and see how much of them will buy the candy or not. If this case, X is how much they like sweetness, Y is 0/1 representing if they buy candy or not. So will scale of fond of sweetness change the regression? For some self-generated data, it looks like that if you change the scale of X from 0/1/2 to -1/0/2, the fitting will be changed

Comment: @user1285419 That will indeed change your answer, since in the second case, you're effectively saying that the difference between Neutral and Satisfied is twice as large as the difference between Dissatisfied and Neutral, whereas in the first case, they are the same. This is why it may not be appropriate to use methods built for continuous numerical data - see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877129715200196.

Comment: Thanks. I am reading it. So in social science, it is a very high chance that we have some data representing the dependence of effect against some degree of something (increasing value). For example, people will have depression or not dependent on their satisfaction in life. In this case, Y is boolean while X is a discrete variable of 5 values. I read some articles that people just fit X into Y such that Y=f(X), then they use f to estimate how general X affects the Y. Is that correct to do that when Y is binary? Any articles you recommend to see how they due with that statistically?